# (Linux) File/Directory encryption instead of filesystem encryption?

Tags: linux, encryption

I have problems setting up filesystem encryption (I'll be honest, it's a bit too complicated for me). Is there a feature like EFS from Windows where I can simply encrypt directory and/or files?

Comment: The technology exists, but I'm unaware of a user-friendly way to do it. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/369623/20358) might get you part of the way there, but the instructions it links to specifically work only for encrypting the home drive.

Comment: Might also want to take a look at this (for non-rotational drive): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332554/how-to-f2fs-filesystem-encryption

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html provides information in encrypting any filesystem you wish, and https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-with-ecryptfs-on-ubuntu-16-04/ describes how to encrypt a specific directory, its files, and directories and files beneath.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I'll read those and try them in a VM first :)

Comment: Take a look at Plasma Vaults. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-an-encrypted-vault-with-kde-vaults/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [EncFS](https://vgough.github.io/encfs/) a try:

> EncFS provides an encrypted filesystem in user-space. It runs with regular user permissions using the FUSE library. EncFS is Open Source software.

Basic usage:

`$ encfs ~/.encrypted_data ~/clear_data`

That will create a ~/.encrypted_data and will mount the unencrypted version as ~/clear_data (your user needs to be in the *fuse* group)

You only interact with ~/clear_data, and everything in that mount will be encrypted in the real directory ~/.encrypted_data

Once you are done, you can remove the unencrypted mount with:

`fusermount -u ~/clear_data`